# AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?)

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I have the impala query:

```
select id,zip,income
from zipcode_incomes
group by income
having income>avg(income)
```

but i am getting error, AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?). What mistake did I make?

Comment: What are you trying to do.. Add sample data and expected result. Am sure fixing the error alone will not solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have non-aggregated columns in the `select`.  Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select id, zip, income
from (select zi.*, avg(zi.income) over () as avg_income
      from zipcode_incomes zi
     ) zi
where income > avg_income;
```

This returns zip codes whose income is larger than the overall average.